# Как добавить отступ справа для текста?

Tags: html, css

Как добавить отступ справа для текста?

https://unbrokenteam.ru/

В style.css у меня:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Мне это нужно, чтобы между черной шапкой с лого и границами экрана слева, справа и сверху не было пустого пространства.

Добавил в style.css

```css
.text_padding{
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

Применил этот стиль в index.html к тексту:

```html
<div class="myDivBlueBackground"><div class="text_padding"><div class="grey"><p>Большинство юридических фирм предлагает тарифы на юридическое обслуживание, которыми предусмотрен определенный перечень услуг за определенную сумму. Например, тариф в 15 000 рублей за 3 консультации, 3 договора, 2 претензии, 1 внесение изменений в ЕГРЮЛ и 1 выезд юриста. И даже если Вы не воспользовались этими услугами все равно придётся заплатить. 
      <p>Я предлагаю Вам выбирать и использовать те услуги, которые Вам реально нужны здесь и сейчас. Если Вы не пользуетесь моими услугами, то и платить соответственно не нужно.</p> 
      <p>Кроме того, компаниям, заключившим договор на юридическое обслуживание, предоставляется скидка в размере 10% на иные услуги (например, участие в переговорах, защита в суде и.т.п.).</p>
      <p><strong>Платите только за работу!</strong></p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Почему текст не сдвинулся вправо?

[index.html](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/qkGb/eRZe29sPk)
[style.css](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ZBGt/QiYKZuABV)

Comment: попробуйте padding вместо маржина

Comment: Всё прекрасно сдвинулось - просто Вы эти 10px не видите. Сделайте, например, 100px, и сразу станет заметно

Comment: Добавил файлы index.html и style.css. Не сдвинулось. Нужно, чтобы текст был немного подальше от левой границы экрана. Особенно, что касается списка <ul> с <li>

Comment: "текст подальше от левой границы" - это padding/margin left (для понимания, "отступ-слева: 10пикселей") А ты используешь, right. В ответах есть рабочий вариант

Answer (score 1):

Способ №1. Через `padding`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.text_padding {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDivBlueBackground">
  <div class="text_padding">
    <div class="grey">
      <p>Большинство юридических фирм предлагает тарифы на юридическое обслуживание, которыми предусмотрен определенный перечень услуг за определенную сумму. Например, тариф в 15 000 рублей за 3 консультации, 3 договора, 2 претензии, 1 внесение изменений
        в ЕГРЮЛ и 1 выезд юриста. И даже если Вы не воспользовались этими услугами все равно придётся заплатить.
        <p>Я предлагаю Вам выбирать и использовать те услуги, которые Вам реально нужны здесь и сейчас. Если Вы не пользуетесь моими услугами, то и платить соответственно не нужно.</p>
        <p>Кроме того, компаниям, заключившим договор на юридическое обслуживание, предоставляется скидка в размере 10% на иные услуги (например, участие в переговорах, защита в суде и.т.п.).</p>
        <p><strong>Платите только за работу!</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Способ №2. Через `margin`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text_padding {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDivBlueBackground">
  <div class="text_padding">
    <div class="grey">
      <p>Большинство юридических фирм предлагает тарифы на юридическое обслуживание, которыми предусмотрен определенный перечень услуг за определенную сумму. Например, тариф в 15 000 рублей за 3 консультации, 3 договора, 2 претензии, 1 внесение изменений
        в ЕГРЮЛ и 1 выезд юриста. И даже если Вы не воспользовались этими услугами все равно придётся заплатить.
        <p>Я предлагаю Вам выбирать и использовать те услуги, которые Вам реально нужны здесь и сейчас. Если Вы не пользуетесь моими услугами, то и платить соответственно не нужно.</p>
        <p>Кроме того, компаниям, заключившим договор на юридическое обслуживание, предоставляется скидка в размере 10% на иные услуги (например, участие в переговорах, защита в суде и.т.п.).</p>
        <p><strong>Платите только за работу!</strong></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Голосую за padding